# Jenkins Publish over FTP sending the entire site instead of updated files

Tags: ssh, ftp, svn, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server installed on my local server. I have managed to build artifacts from svn repository and deploy to a remote server using 'Publish over SSH' and 'Publish over FTP' but my problem is that every time a new revision is built under Jenkins, it published/copies the entire site instead of the updated files only which is undesirable especially for uploading immediate updates.

Is there a way I could tell Jenkins, either way via 'Publish over Ftp' or 'Publish over SSH', to publish/copy only updated files or latest revision to my remote server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANT as build task runner with a [FTP task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html). With the property **depends** setted to yes.

By guide:

> transfers only new or changed files if set to "yes". Defaults to "no".

Comment: Yes, I've been through that but I'm having this errror 
`FATAL: Unable to find build script at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testbuild/workspace/build.xml`...

Comment: @PinoyPal and then you googled that error and followed instructions and then what happened? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108079/jenkins-error-fatal-unable-to-find-build-script-at-c-selenium-tests-for-moveon